# For a family of elliptic curves $E\rightarrow S$ over a scheme $S$ when does $\Omega_{E/S}$ have a global section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609788/elliptic-curve-and-differential-form-determine-weierstrass-equation) question it is stated that for a family of elliptic curves $E \rightarrow S$ over a scheme $S$ there isn't always a global section of the sheaf of relative 1-forms $\Omega^1_{E/S}$. There is a reference to a book of Katz and Mazur, but I don't quite get what the condition on $S$ is for such a global section to exist. Could someone shed some light on this?

Many thanks.

Comment: In the article https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/rossler/mypage/pdf-files/fin-cf.pdf, sec. 3.2, a family $B_{1,1}\to H_{1,1}$ is constructed, where the sheaf of relative differentials is a torsion line bundle of order $12$ (precisely). In particular, it cannot have a global section.

Comment: Sorry I realise that this does not quite answer your question. It only proves that the sheaf of differentials cannot have a *trivialising* section in the described situation. I will think about this some more.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you for the reference.